# Instagram Real-time Photo Updates Subscriptions c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, instagram-api, subscriptions, real-time-updates

I'm developing an asp mvc .net application and I'm trying to subscribe to Instagram Real-time updates. I've been searching and reading but I have not found and answer to my problem. My subscription code looks like:

```
                string accessToken = context.AccessToken;
            //Subscribing to Instagram real-time updates
            NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();
            parameters.Add("client_id", myClientId);
            parameters.Add("client_secret", myClientSecret);
            parameters.Add("object", "user");
            parameters.Add("aspect", "media");
            parameters.Add("verify_token", context.AccessToken);
            parameters.Add("callback_url", @"https://xmovo.org/Instagram/Update");

            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            var responseAsync = client.UploadValuesTaskAsync(
                new Uri(@"https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/"),
                "POST",
                parameters);

            string response = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(await responseAsync);
```

I defined a controller called "Instagram" and an action called "Update" that answer to GET and POST, but I'm getting this: "- Response: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.".
  I would appreciate some help.
  Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting that error when you run your program or is that error being thrown when Instagram sends an update to your callback url?

Comment: Also, are you able to add a breakpoint to your controller action to see if Instagram actually call it back? The moment you subscribe, you should actually have a GET request to your action that you need to respond to in a certain way....

Comment: Actually the exception is thrown by the UploadValuesTaskAsync method. Instagram never send me the GET request...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! callback_url can't be https. Now my application is working!